# Data transfer between local server and AWS server

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

We have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that reads data locally from within the same server. This server is in Europe. However when trying to read the same data from an AWS server based in Sidney the lag is many times greater. A ping from our local server to the AWS server in Australia takes 5 seconds. The data needs to be located in Australia because of data protection laws issued by the Australian Government. The database is MySQL. We have created a VPN between both servers and made no difference.

What are our options in order to improve the speed between these two servers?

Comment: Can you also deploy your application to the Sydney region to reduce the latency? Can your application use caching to reduce the number of database reads? (Won't help latency but can cut down on reads.)

Answer (score -1):

If it is a web application serving content to users over internet you can use CloudFront distribution to reduce your latency issues.
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

If you are trying to connect your servers from your data center to AWS

Use AWS Direct Connect, this will provide a dedicated link between your on-premise datacenter and to the AWS Servers; Decreasing your latency by a lot.
https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/

AWS runs your application regardless of which platform(ASP.NET, JAVA, C...) it is, AWS only provisions infrastructure. You don't need to worry about the platform on which your application is running and what database it connects to. You just need to ensure that all the network connections are properly open so that your servers can communicate with AWS servers.

Comment: AWS Direct Connect is beyond my current budget, is there not any other possibility we can implement?

Comment: The other option is VPN(which you have already done). Try checking if your VPN server is able to handle all your network load. Which VPN server have you configured? Is it able provide the required Bandwith for your network load?-----------------You can always contact AWS Support(Email support if you are not a Partner). They always have a solution way out of such things